# How to find out if an MSI I just installed requested a Windows reboot?

Tags: c#, windows, installation, windows-installer

I've built a `setup.exe` in C# that runs several chained MSI's (with the `/QUIET /NORESTART`). At the end I'd like to check if a reboot is needed in the machine (that is, if one of the MSI's requested a reboot).

How can I detect so?

Comment: I've even seen this utility: http://exodusdev.com/products/whyreboot
which knows not only that a restart is needed, but also WHY...
How do I retrieve such information programmatically? Registry?

Comment: See follow up to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689610/how-to-detect-programmatically-when-the-install-updates-and-shut-down-the-comput

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following registry location has the information:

Key `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`, value `PendingFileRenameOperations`

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx

Comment: I have a machine without PendingFileRenameOperations showing the little shield in the "Shut down" button. How come?

Comment: Doesn't that shield in the shutdown button mean "Install updates and shutdown"? That's not equivalent to a required restart.

Comment: ok... do you know then how to detect taht shield? I put that as a separate question and someone complained that it was a duplicate of this one :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to accomplish this is to check the exit codes of all of the MSIs that you run in your code. **If an MSI has an exit code of 3010 then it requires a reboot.** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368542.aspx).


Assuming that you're using `System.Diagnostics.Process` to run the MSIs and after the process has exited, you would retrieve the processes exit code using the `ExitCode` property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode(v=vs.90).aspx).


So, you can simply check the exit code of an MSI process and when you're done running all of your MSIs, if any of them returned 3010 then you know you need to reboot.

Comment: I have learned that some MSIs will not use an exit code of 3010 if the system is already pending a restart when you run the MSI.

Microsoft's .NET Framework 4.5.2 offline installer is an example of one such MSI that exhibits this behavior.  It simply returns an exit code of 0 if you run it again without having re-booted between executions of the MSI.

Comment: @user16563 Thanks for the info, it's good to know. Yet another great example of how confusingly inconsistent Windows tends to function. :)

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Vinko Vrsalovic's helfpul answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685861/45375) with a **PowerShell** command:

```
$rebootPending = $null -ne 
  (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager').PendingFileRenameOperations
```

Note that `$rebootPending` equalling `$true` indicates that a system reboot is pending for *any* reason, not just due to MSI-based installations.