# How to detect programmatically when the "Install Updates and shut down the computer" shield icon is present on top of the Start / "Shut down" button?

Tags: c#, windows

Some updates put that little shield indicating that the computer needs to be rebooted. Is that shield a registry key? I thought it was the key:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations
```

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx

But my computer is showing the icon right now, and there is no PendingFileRenameOperations in the registry, so obviously it's something else, or a combination of things !?

Comment: See initial question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685821/how-to-find-out-if-a-windows-restart-is-needed

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Windows Update Agent API to find if a reboot is currently required to complete an update.

[ISystemInformation::RebootRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386098(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: I'd say this is not exactly what the question asks. The question asks (more or less) how to see if there are pending updates to install.

Comment: This script should give a clue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387102(VS.85).aspx